# Comapring ObjectId using mongoose problem even after using .toString()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, filter

I understand this is a really long post, but I would truly appreciate it lots if someone could have a look and help me out, I'm really stuck.

So, I'm really new to node mongoose and express. I'm basically building an e-commerce node app and I'm working with mongoose, my `Schema of the users`, has an embedded `cart array` with `productIds` which reference to a `products` document. Here's how a `user` record looks like:

```
_id: ObjectId("60e4945782dd90266470044d")
email: "test@test.com"
password: "$2a$12$ARK.2yNm/AiRJ/rkNRLXu.ZGZiQkm/hXnacxe407KlUdeZ8lzKCh6"
cart: [
        {
          _id: ObjectId("60e9f7102a4c6217045f68ba")
          productId: ObjectId("60e765882e3162092451966c")
          quantity: 2
        },
        {
          _id: ObjectId("60e9f7122a4c6217045f68c0")
          productId: ObjectId("60e764b62e31620924519667")
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
```

This would be the `product` document record:

```
_id: ObjectId:("60e764b62e31620924519667")
images:[]
title:"Book"
price:200,
userId : ObjectId("60e4945782dd90266470044d")}
```

I have added a method to my `user` model `removeFromCart` to delete a product from the cart it accepts a `productId`, which is sent from a controller, which handles a post request, the `prodId` comes from a `ejs` `input` where I loop through `cart` and send the `product` Id(check code below for the `console.log` of `prodId` here). I stored the user with a session in `req.user`, so I can use the mongoose features :

```
exports.postDeleteFromCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  console.log('this is the id from the post request body', prodId)
  req.user.removeFromCart(prodId)
  res.redirect('/cart')
};
```

This is the `method` `removeFromCart`, which I have included in my `user` model.

```
userSchema.methods.removeFromCart = function (prodId) {
  console.log('this is the argument from the function', prodId.toString())
  const updatedCart = this.cart.filter((item) => {
    console.log('this is the productId inside the cart', item.productId.toString())
    return item.productId.toString() !== prodId.toString()
  });
  console.log(updatedCart);
};
```

Here is the interesting part, when I run this I'm expecting a `console.log` of the `updatedCart` which doesn't have the `product` I wanted to remove. Instead I get this `console.log` in the `terminal`:

```
this is the id from the post request body 60e765882e3162092451966c 
this is the argument from the function 60e765882e3162092451966c 
this is the productId inside the cart 60e765882e3162092451966c
this is the productId inside the cart 60e764b62e31620924519667
this is the updated cart: [
  {
    _id: 60e9f7102a4c6217045f68ba,
    productId: 60e765882e3162092451966c,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 60e9f7122a4c6217045f68c0,
    productId: 60e764b62e31620924519667,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
```

I have two `products` inside the `cart array` and I'm expecting one to be deleted since the `filter` method should return only those `products` that don't have the same `productId`, which comes from the `cart` elements and `prodId` from the argument. But from the log up there we can see that nothing changed from the `updatedCart` even though these `console.logs` that display the `id` are all the same which would mean one element must be removed.

```
this is the argument from the function 60e765882e3162092451966c 
this is the productId inside the cart 60e765882e3162092451966c
```

But, it isn't the case since I get returned the `updatedCart` array with an element with that exact `productId` which should be removed but isn't.

```
this is the updated cart: [
  {
    _id: 60e9f7102a4c6217045f68ba,
    productId: 60e765882e3162092451966c,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 60e9f7122a4c6217045f68c0,
    productId: 60e764b62e31620924519667,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
```

In advance thank you for your time I know this was a long post. I'm really thankful!

Comment: Well formed question, with a well explained problem and relevant code, so +1. Believe me, not all questions are written like yours. Now I know Mongoose can be a pain to work with, especially wih `ObjectID.toString()` and immutable objects. But you don't need to design your own method to delete objects from a nested array, Mongoose can do this natively. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640164/mongoose-remove-an-object-from-a-nested-array (`user.$.cart` I believe the syntax is)

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you for your time and your answer, this helped my solve my problem my code now works, I'm honestly really grateful, you've made my day. Have a nice one!